# Does anyone know about the principle of pnorm method in residual after chisq.test?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, residuals

I found the website which explain about residuals after chisq. test.
The website explain below the Method of calculation.

```
res$expected
          [,1] [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 1.8333333  4.4 4.033333 0.7333333
[2,] 2.3333333  5.6 5.133333 0.9333333
[3,] 0.8333333  2.0 1.833333 0.3333333

res$residuals
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  1.6001894  0.2860388 -1.0124568 -0.85634884
[2,] -1.5275252  0.5916080  0.3825184  0.06900656
[3,]  0.1825742 -1.4142136  0.8616404  1.15470054

res$stdres
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  2.202652  0.4640162 -1.5986161 -1.1138229
[2,] -2.291288  1.0458250  0.6581681  0.0978076
[3,]  0.219089 -2.0000000  1.1860432  1.3093073

pnorm(abs(res$stdres), lower.tail=FALSE)*2
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.02761930 0.64263616 0.1099059 0.2653552
[2,] 0.02194677 0.29564182 0.5104301 0.9220851
[3,] 0.82658070 0.04550026 0.2356052 0.1904303
```

I understand from res-expected to res-stdres, but I cannot understand why `pnorm(abs(res$stdres), lower.tail=FALSE)*2` can calculate each residuals p-value.

Does anyone know the principle, or reference that related this method?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could link to &/or quote from the website in question.

Comment: Thanks for your edited! it is the link→　http://aoki2.si.gunma-u.ac.jp/R/my-chisq-test.html 　It's in Japanese but I hope you can understand..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't read Japanese, & Google translate doesn't seem to work on the page for some reason. Can you translate & paste in the explanation? I'm not sure if this will be answerable otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This website said that R can calculate chi-squared test and also can calculate residuals, but after that we have to calculate adjusted residuals ourselves. so this website explain how to do that. this website tell that res$expected=Expected value , res-residuals=Standardized residual, and res-stdres= adjusted residuals, pnorm(abs(res-stdres), lower.tail=FALSE)*2 = p-value. But only that this website don't explain why pnorm(abs(res-stdres), lower.tail=FALSE)*2 can calculate p-value.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to use this method in my research, therefore I have to know the principle to use it because I have to explain about it on my paper. But I don't understand the meaning this code..

Answer (score 0):

From r documentation (try ?pnorm) we see that:

> pnorm(q, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
>
> ...
>
> pnorm gives the distribution function
>
> ....
>
> lower.tail    logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x] otherwise, P[X > x].

Putting it together

> pnorm(abs(res$stdres), lower.tail=FALSE)*2

is computing $2 \times P(Z > |\text{stdres}|)$ which is the $p$-value computation if the standardized residuals are assumed to have a standard normal distribution and if the test is two-tailed.

Comment: I see! Yes, I understand. Thank you for your reply!